# JavaFx handler override

Tags: javafx, overriding

I have a fxml file build from fxml builder and I am using it by a loader in Java.

```
URL resource = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("fxmlFile.fxml");

FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(resource, resourceBundle);
Pane rootPane = (Pane) loader.load();
```

this fxml file maps click event to my class;

```
<Group id="Group" layoutX="0.0" layoutY="0.0" onMouseReleased="#handleThis" scaleX="1.0" scaleY="1.0">
...
<Group/>
```

so I implement my handler in my class, lets call it MyClass;

```
public class MyClass {
public void createScene() throws IOException
{
    URL resource = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("fxmlFile.fxml");

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(resource, resourceBundle);
    Pane rootPane = (Pane) loader.load(); 
    ...
}

@FXML
public void handleThis(ActionEvent event) {
    System.out.println("from MyClass");
}
        ...
}
```

Now I extend MyClass as MyExtendedClass and override handleThis method;

```
public class MyExtendedClass extends MyClass {
    @Override
    public void handleThis(ActionEvent event) {
           System.out.println("from MyExtendedClass");
    }
}
```

My question is, I cannot manage to work handle method in my extended class. It does not overrides it. How can I achieve to make it print "from MyExtendedClass" instead of "from MyClass"?

Comment: What are you declaring as the controller in the FXML file?

Comment: have you tried onMouseRelease="#MyExtendedClass.handleThis" ?

Comment: I set controller as MyClass and I should not change it

Comment: Then how would the `FXMLLoader` even know about the subclass?

Comment: FXMLLoader is called in MyClass

Comment: I'm confused now. You are loading the FXML file from the same class that you declare as the controller class? Why would you do that? Perhaps you need to rewrite your question to explain more about what you are really trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `createScene()` is called on an instance of MyExtendedClass, the FXMLLoader parses the FXML file, reads the `fx:controller="MyClass"` attribute and instantiates a **new** object of type **MyClass**. That is why the base method is always called. The FXMLLoader doesn't know about MyExtendedClass.

There is a - hackish - way to achieve what you want (i.e. doing the loading in MyClass and still defining the controller in FXML):

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void createScene()
    {
        try
        {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("FXML.fxml"));
            // set a controller factory that returns this instance as controller
            // (works in this case, but not recommended)
            loader.setControllerFactory(controllerType -> this);
            pane = (Pane) loader.load();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

---

It would be cleaner to instantiate the controller and pass it to the FXMLLoader.
For this the `fx:controller=""` attribute must be removed from the FXML file.

```
public class Main extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        MyClass controller = new MyExtendedClass();

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("FXML.fxml"));
        loader.setController(controller);
        Pane pane = (Pane) loader.load();

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(pane));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Or use `fx:controller="MyClass"` to define the base type in the FXML file and let a controller factory decide the actual implementation.

```
public class Main extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("FXML.fxml"));
        loader.setControllerFactory(controllerType -> {
            if (MyClass.class.equals(controllerType))
                return new MyExtendedClass();
            else
                return null; // return some other controller
        });
        Pane pane = (Pane) loader.load();

        MyClass controller = (MyClass) loader.getController();

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(pane));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```